# Draw line after zoom and pan in canvas on cursor point correcting-coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, svelte

I am creating a canvas with multiple image which have zoom and pan action in Svelte application. And now want to draw line on it after disable zoom and pan. Zoom and pan working well but I cannot draw line on the canvas after zoom and pan disabled as expected. Unable to draw line on cursor point or correcting-coordinates. It's drawing far from cursor and moving the line too far on mouse move.

I am giving full code here so that any one can run it in Svelte application to see it

I tried so many ways but can't solve it.

```
<script>
import { onMount } from "svelte";

import { f7ready } from "framework7-svelte";

let canvasWidth = 500;
let canvasHeight = 500;
let ctx;
let canvas;
let isDrawing = false;
let start;
var scaleFactor = 1.1;
var factor = 1.1;
let canDragAndZoom = true;
let t, l;

$: ctx;
$: canvas;
$: isDrawing;
$: start;
$: t;
$: l;
$: scaleFactor;
$: factor;
$: canDragAndZoom;

let lastX = canvasWidth;
let lastY = canvasHeight;
$: lastX;
$: lastY;

onMount(() => {
    f7ready(async () => {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
        canvas.height = canvasHeight;

        var gkhead1 = new Image();
        var gkhead2 = new Image();
        var gkhead3 = new Image();
        var gkhead4 = new Image();
        var gkhead5 = new Image();

        gkhead1.src =
            "http://localhost/asset_ims/assets/uploads/files/canvasImg1.jpeg";
        gkhead2.src =
            "http://localhost/asset_ims/assets/uploads/files/canvasImg2.jpeg";
        gkhead3.src =
            "http://localhost/asset_ims/assets/uploads/files/canvasImg3.jpeg";
        gkhead4.src =
            "http://localhost/asset_ims/assets/uploads/files/canvasImg4.jpeg";
        gkhead5.src =
            "http://localhost/asset_ims/assets/uploads/files/canvasImg5.jpeg";

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        trackTransforms(ctx);

        function redraw() {
            // Clear the entire canvas
            var p1 = ctx.transformedPoint(0, 0);
            var p2 = ctx.transformedPoint(canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.clearRect(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);

            ctx.save();
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.restore();

            ctx.drawImage(gkhead1, 50, 150, 100, 129);
            ctx.drawImage(gkhead2, 135, 150, 100, 194);
            ctx.drawImage(gkhead3, 240, 150, 100, 141);
            ctx.drawImage(gkhead4, 345, 150, 100, 125);
            ctx.drawImage(gkhead5, 50, 300, 100, 75);
        }

        redraw();

        var dragStart, dragged;

        canvas.addEventListener(
            "mousedown",
            function (evt) {
                document.body.style.mozUserSelect =
                    document.body.style.WebkitUserSelect =
                    document.body.style.userSelect =
                    document.body.style.msUserSelect =
                        "auto";

                // drag code

                lastX = evt.offsetX || evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                lastY = evt.offsetY || evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
                dragStart = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX, lastY);

                // drag code

                dragged = false;
            },
            false
        );

        canvas.addEventListener(
            "mousemove",
            function (evt) {
                lastX = evt.offsetX || evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                lastY = evt.offsetY || evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
                dragged = true;
                dragStart = canDragAndZoom ? dragStart : null;
                if (dragStart) {
                    var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX, lastY);
                    ctx.translate(pt.x - dragStart.x, pt.y - dragStart.y);
                    redraw();
                }
            },
            false
        );

        canvas.addEventListener(
            "mouseup",
            function (evt) {
                dragStart = null;
                if (!dragged) zoom(evt.shiftKey ? -1 : 1);
            },
            false
        );

        // var scaleFactor = 1.1;

        var zoom = function (clicks) {
            if (!canDragAndZoom) {
                return false;
            }
            var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX, lastY);
            ctx.translate(pt.x, pt.y);
            factor = Math.pow(scaleFactor, clicks);
            ctx.scale(factor, factor);
            ctx.translate(-pt.x, -pt.y);
            redraw();
        };

        var handleScroll = function (evt) {
            var delta = evt.wheelDelta
                ? evt.wheelDelta / 40
                : evt.detail
                ? -evt.detail
                : 0;
            if (delta) zoom(delta);
            return evt.preventDefault() && false;
        };

        canvas.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", handleScroll, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel", handleScroll, false);
        // };
    });
});

$: if (ctx) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
}

const handleStart = ({ offsetX: x, offsetY: y }) => {
    isDrawing = true;
    start = { x, y };
};

const handleEnd = () => {
    isDrawing = false;
};

const dragEnable = () => {
    canDragAndZoom = canDragAndZoom ? false : true;
};
const handleMove = (event) => {
    if (!isDrawing) return;

    let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    let currentX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    let currentY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    const { x, y } = start;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    context.stroke();

    start = { x: currentX, y: currentY };
};

function trackTransforms(ctx) {
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    var xform = svg.createSVGMatrix();
    ctx.getTransform = function () {
        return xform;
    };

    var savedTransforms = [];
    var save = ctx.save;
    ctx.save = function () {
        savedTransforms.push(xform.translate(0, 0));
        return save.call(ctx);
    };

    var restore = ctx.restore;
    ctx.restore = function () {
        xform = savedTransforms.pop();
        return restore.call(ctx);
    };

    var scale = ctx.scale;
    ctx.scale = function (sx, sy) {
        xform = xform.scaleNonUniform(sx, sy);
        return scale.call(ctx, sx, sy);
    };

    var rotate = ctx.rotate;
    ctx.rotate = function (radians) {
        xform = xform.rotate((radians * 180) / Math.PI);
        return rotate.call(ctx, radians);
    };

    var translate = ctx.translate;
    ctx.translate = function (dx, dy) {
        xform = xform.translate(dx, dy);
        return translate.call(ctx, dx, dy);
    };

    var transform = ctx.transform;
    ctx.transform = function (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        var m2 = svg.createSVGMatrix();
        m2.a = a;
        m2.b = b;
        m2.c = c;
        m2.d = d;
        m2.e = e;
        m2.f = f;
        xform = xform.multiply(m2);
        return transform.call(ctx, a, b, c, d, e, f);
    };

    var setTransform = ctx.setTransform;
    ctx.setTransform = function (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        xform.a = a;
        xform.b = b;
        xform.c = c;
        xform.d = d;
        xform.e = e;
        xform.f = f;
        return setTransform.call(ctx, a, b, c, d, e, f);
    };

    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    ctx.transformedPoint = function (x, y) {
        pt.x = x;
        pt.y = y;
        return pt.matrixTransform(xform.inverse());
    };
}
</script>

<canvas
id="myCanvas"
bind:this={canvas}
on:mousedown={handleStart}
on:mouseup={handleEnd}
on:mouseleave={handleEnd}
on:mousemove={handleMove}
/>

<a href="#" on:click={dragEnable}>
  <i class="f7-icons presc_icon">pencil_outline</i>
</a>
```

Comment: All those reactive statements in the form `$: ctx;` are pointless, they do not do anything except possibly declare a variable, which also can be done with just `let`. (All of those already have a corresponding `let`.)

Answer (score 0):

After so many try and lots of effort i was able to solve the issue and now it is working as expected .

just had to add some line in handleMove function .

I am posting the solution as answer here so that any one next time can learn it and use the whole code with answer .

```
  const handleMove = (event) => {

    if (!isDrawing) return;

    let currentX = event.offsetX;
    let currentY = event.offsetY;
    const { x, y } = start;

   let startx = ctx.transformedPoint(x, y);
   let endy = ctx.transformedPoint(currentX, currentY);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startx.x, startx.y);
    ctx.lineTo(endy.x, endy.y);
    ctx.stroke();

    start = { x: currentX, y: currentY };
   };
```